# How to import "targets" in sugarCRM directly without using the uploader?

Tags: sugarcrm

I need to import a large number of targets into sugarCRM 5.5.2 and i don't want to use the import function. i understand that i have to insert data into the "email_addresses", "email_addr_bean_rel" and "prospect" table, the main question is how to generate the "bean_id" in the "email_addr_bean_rel". Are there fixed rules for generating it or can i use a random hash?

Answer (score 0):

The bean_id in the email_addr_bean_rel table should match the id of the record you created in the prospects table. That table is used as a join table between the email_addresses table and the various bean module tables ( such as prospects ).